# Geocoding single address with Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geocoding

I'm trying to find a plug-in on a leaflet in which the user will enter the address, and the HTML (aka the plug-in) will geocode the location and will return a latitude and longitude. So I have tried the [Leaflet-Control Geocoder](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder), but I cannot find the lat, long.

Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the Leaflet Control Geocoder plugin [API documentation](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#customizing), you should:

1. Attach an event on the `"markgeocode"` event of the `L.Control.geocoder` object.
2. Read the [`event.geocode.center`](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder#properties) LatLng object that is passed to your event listener.

```js
var geocoder = L.Control.geocoder()
.on('markgeocode', function(event) {
    var center = event.geocode.center;
    L.marker(center).addTo(map);
    map.setView(center, map.getZoom());
})
.addTo(map);
```

Demo: http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/robi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Alas, the link to the demo seems to be broken :-(